# typescript debug with internet explorer sourcemap not loading

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, debugging, typescript, source-maps

I have setup a very simple visual studio (2013) web application using typescript with require.js

Here is my app.ts file:

```
class test_class{
     say_hello(){
         return 'hello world';
     }
}

(function(){
     var test: test_class = new test_class();   <-- **here I set a breakpoint**
     test.say_hello();
}());
```

And in the index.html I reference the generated index.js (using amd require.js):

```
<script data-main="appfile" src="require.js"></script>
```

And here is the line at the end of the generated appfile.js file

```
//# sourceMappingURL=appfile.js.map
```

both files appfile.js and require.js are in the same directory, on the root. When I start the debugger from within visual studio, my .ts breakpoint is not hit. In fact my .ts is not loaded at all. On the output window there is this error message:

**SourceMap http://localhost:1631/appfile.js.map read failed: The operation has timed out.The thread 0x16a4 has exited with code 259 (0x103)**

Only once, and completely randomly, it has loaded the .ts file and I have been able to hit my breakpoint. Is this a known issue with internet explorer: being unable to load sourcemap files (in chrome it works perfectly but i want to debug in visual studio)

I have look for a similar error message over the internet and google without success. For the pass couple of days I have been trying to setup a simple typescript project in visual studio (2013/2015) and see how debugging goes. But it looks like it is almost impossible to debug typescript within visual studio. 
Any hint, any suggestion pointing me to the right direction about successfully debugging .ts files in visual studio (2013/2015) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: For any one with the same problem, here is the answer: [How to create basic TypeScript project using jQuery, RequireJS, and KnockoutJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924288/how-to-create-basic-typescript-project-using-jquery-requirejs-and-knockoutjs)

Comment: According to StackOverflow rules, it's fine to answer your own question. You should post your comment as an answer and accept it.